# Short One-Session Adventures for AD&D 1e?

Tags: game-recommendation, adnd-1e, published-adventures, system-introduction

My group and I are planning to play a simple trial session with AD&D 1e just to learn the basics of the game. We agreed that this adventure would not be connected to the larger campaign introduced in the following weeks.

I am therefore looking for any AD&D 1e adventures/modules that

- are designed for 4-6 players
- are designed for level one characters
- feature a simplistic plot
- require little preparation
- are completable in 2-4 hours
- take place in a dungeon
- feature only classical fantasy monsters (goblins, trolls, orcs, etc.)
- provide a good introduction to the game

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, then this does not fit our site format.  Read the help center and meta on why we don't do unbounded list questions and our requirements for recommendation questions.  You may just want a big random batch of stuff to pick from, and that's fine, but not part of our format here.

Comment: This question (and the general issue here) is being discussed [on meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3398/1204).

Comment: These requirements capture almost all AD&D adventures for low-level characters, which is not a small number.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [this adventure](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/php4/archive.php?sectioninit=FE&fileid=295&watchfile=0) from Dragonsfoot.org, which has the benefit of being free. It is designed for 4-6 players of 1st level who are of 'novice or intermediate' skill, so it's pretty much perfect for the group composition. The contents of the adventure are rather straightforward. A Meazle has secretly made its home in a small village and is stealing from the inhabitants. It's also responsible for the murder of a local. The players have to find out where the mystery thief's lair is and then get the loot back while finding out the local's fate. You should be able to wrap it up in 3-4 hours, although in case it drags on you can let the NPC who may tag along with the group find some more clues.

By the way, Dragonsfoot is generally a great site for 1st edition resources. They have a bunch more adventures, a load of custom spells, character sheets, and even more. (I'm not affiliated in any way, I just think they're awesome)

Answer (score 1):

Four hours is a pretty short requirement, and since this is going to be a learning session it's probably going to go more slowly and even further limit what you can accomplish.  The one that comes to mind that might be most suitable is N1 ([Against the Cult of the Reptile God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_the_Cult_of_the_Reptile_God)), which was an interesting (if sometimes stereotypical) adventure designed for novice GMs and players.